# Как прикрепить вложение к сообщению VK используя библиотеку VK.NET?

Tags: c#, vkontakte-api, вконтакте, enum

Метод Message.Send(param) принимает обьект особого типа.
Одно из полей обьекта (Attachment) отвечает за вложения к сообщению.
Тип этого поля `IEnumerable<MediaAttachment>`, где  MediaAttachment - абстрактный класс.

Как заполнить это поле?

> Из документации:
>
> Attachment - Медиавложения к личному сообщению, перечисленные через запятую. Каждое прикрепление представлено в формате: `<type><owner_id><media_id>`.

[ссылка на описание функции](https://vknet.github.io/vk/messages/send/)

```
MessagesSendParams param = new MessagesSendParams();

param.Domain = user.Domain;
param.Attachment=?;

Messages.Send(VkNet.Model.RequestParams.MessagesSendParams param);

IEnumerable<MediaAttachment>
```

Comment: Проблема ВК в том, что прежде чем что-то прикрепить, это надо залить в ВК и получить ссылку на этот файл, а потом уже параметры ссылки добавлять

Answer (score -3):

Достань сервер для аттачмента (методы могут быть разными в зависимости то ли от места где тебе нужен аттачмент то ли от типа аттачмента -- не помню уже, потому не скажу точнее. Ищи по документации.)

Залей сам аттачмент на сервер получив в ответ обьект этого самого класса "медиаАттачмент"

и прикрепляй к сообщению.

Точнее копошится влом, я этим давно игрался.